# Why js console prints the correct value, but also undefined?

Tags: javascript, html, function, console, output

i have this function example, but when I run it in js console of my browser, i have the expected result, but also an "undefined" in a random(i think is random) position of the results. Is this because the processing time is so much fast? it will be a problem when i need some sorting in future coding?
This is the code:

```js
const myColours = ["yellow", "green", "black", "orange"]

function givemeFour(a,b,c,d,e = "hello") {
   console.log("A", a);
   console.log("B", b);
   console.log("C", c);
   console.log("D", d);
   console.log("E", e);
}

givemeFour(...myColours)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

And this is the output of my console

[image: Output]

Comment: Your console picture is completly wrong, you made it with photoshop ?

Comment: no hahaha, thats the output.

Answer (score 0):

It's printing the value to which the expression you provided evaluates. For example, if you entered `2+2`, it would output `4`. The various expressions you provide are calls to a function that returns nothing (`givemeFour`), so it prints `undefined`.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand what you say, but why the order is different in each run(the order i see in the console)? Thanks so much for your answer.

Comment: Presumably because there are two tasks involved

Answer (score 0):

You're seeing the undefined because the function itself does not return anything. Using function declaration syntax, you need an [explicit return statement](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_return.asp), otherwise you'll see `undefined` log to the console when you invoke the function.  Try adding something like `return "Hello from my function"` to the end of your function. You'll see that logged instead of `undefined`.

You're seeing the `undefined` populate at different points in the console.logs because the console.logs and the function invocation as written aren't depending on one another in terms of their execution timing.